# Oracle Find Table or View or MV References

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Problem:

when I look at a table, or view or mv, I wonder where this table is being used within the database itself. it has the following possibilities:

- update or manipulated through a package
- update through a procedure
- join or referenced with other tables, views or mvs
- called by another database through a DB link

I Java, especially in IDEA like eclipse or netbeans, ctl+shift+g would give you all the 
reference on a object.

how do we achieve this is Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

You may try dba_dependencies (or all_dependecies depending on your privileges) for table references, or search the text field in dba_source for package details.